React Native HTTP request with FormData including an image
My goal is to send a photo from the local device to server.
I used import { launchImageLibrary } from "react-native-image-picker"; to select an asset called photo and used
const resp = await fetch(photo.uri);
const blob = resp.blob();
formData.append('regPhoto', blob);
registerUser(formData);

to append this as a blob to the form data. I checked that the await fetch call is returnin 200 with meaningful data. Then this formData sent with XMLHttpRequest API:
function registerUser(formData: FormData) {
  cl("registerUser");
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", url + "registerUser");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
      const resObj = onReadyStateChange(xhr);
      if (resObj) {
        resolve(resObj);
      }
    };

    xhr.send(formData);
  });
}

Two things happen, the server receives the request without the image and processes it without the image. Which is success to some degree. At the same time, there is a JSON response at the client (android emulator) that reads: Unrecognized formdata part. I am not sure where this is coming from actually.
Does anybody have an idea whats going on here? Just wanted to upload an image to my server via formData.
I tried other methods of appending the photo to the formData but I get the same error.

This question is similar to: how to post an image from react native to django. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

First, ensure you have an image file ready to be uploaded. Typically, you would get this image from the user's device using libraries like react-native-image-picker.
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Button, Image } from 'react-native';
import * as ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';

const UploadImage = () => {
  const [imageUri, setImageUri] = useState(null);

  const selectImage = () => {
    ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary({ mediaType: 'photo' }, (response) => {
      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled image picker');
      } else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
      } else {
        setImageUri(response.assets[0].uri);
      }
    });
  };

  const uploadImage = async () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('photo', {
      uri: imageUri,
      name: 'photo.jpg',
      type: 'image/jpeg'
    });

    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://your-api-endpoint.com/upload', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      });
      const result = await response.json();
      console.log(result);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error uploading image: ', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Button title="Select Image" onPress={selectImage} />
      {imageUri && (
        <View>
          <Image source={{ uri: imageUri }} style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />
          <Button title="Upload Image" onPress={uploadImage} />
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default UploadImage;

npm install axios or yarn add axios
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Button, Image } from 'react-native';
import * as ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';
import axios from 'axios';

const UploadImage = () => {
  const [imageUri, setImageUri] = useState(null);

  const selectImage = () => {
    ImagePicker.launchImageLibrary({ mediaType: 'photo' }, (response) => {
      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled image picker');
      } else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
      } else {
        setImageUri(response.assets[0].uri);
      }
    });
  };

  const uploadImage = async () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('photo', {
      uri: imageUri,
      name: 'photo.jpg',
      type: 'image/jpeg'
    });

    try {
      const response = await axios.post('https://your-api-endpoint.com/upload', formData, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      });
      console.log(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error uploading image: ', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Button title="Select Image" onPress={selectImage} />
      {imageUri && (
        <View>
          <Image source={{ uri: imageUri }} style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />
          <Button title="Upload Image" onPress={uploadImage} />
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default UploadImage;


Thanks, this solved it. i think the issue was that i was using another field besides uri from image selectors result. the field i used did not include the prefix file:// so i am thinking this was the issue. it could also be due to how i added the file to the formData.
